# Showing that $\sqrt{\mathbb E\left(Y^4\right)}\geq \frac{1}{\mathbb E|Y|}$ where $\mathbb E\left(Y^2\right)=1$

Tags: probability-theory

> Show that $$\sqrt{\mathbb E\left(Y^4\right)}\geq \frac{1}{\mathbb
>  E|Y|}$$ where $\mathbb E\left(Y^2\right)=1$ and $\mathbb
>  E\left(Y^4\right)<\infty$

I thought about making sure of Holder's inequality which states that if $p >1$, $q < \infty$, $\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}= 1$, and we have random variables $X\in \mathcal L^p$, $Y\in \mathcal L^q$ then

$$\mathbb E|XY|\leq (\mathbb E|X|^p)^{1/p}(\mathbb E|Y|^q)^{1/q}$$

Since we're given information about $\mathbb E\left(Y^2\right)$ I thought it may be useful to note that

$$\sqrt{\mathbb E\left(Y^4\right)}\geq\sqrt{\mathbb E\left(Y^2\right)\mathbb E\left(Y^2\right)}=1$$

but I couldn't figure out how to make use of either of these to show the desired result.

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to
$$E(Y^4)E(|Y|)^2\ge E(Y^2)^3$$
or to
$$E(Y^4)^{1/3}E(|Y|)^{2/3}\ge E(Y^2).$$
This is Holder, with $1/p=1/3$ and $1/q=2/3$, and
$X=|Y|^{4/3}$ and $Z=|Y|^{2/3}$ in the guise
$$E(|X|^p)^{1/p}E(|Z|^q)^{1/q}\ge E(|XZ|).$$